# My website displays ok on desktop but not on mobile phone screen

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I design my personal website using HTML/CSS. But the text is not scaled to mobile phone. Please refer to images below.

The website on the desktop looks great, and it's not in mobile display.

[Phone display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBlU8.jpg)

My google drive embed is not even fit the phone screen display.
[Phone display GGD PDF Embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPnw.jpg)

What should I do to fix this issue? Thank you so much.

Below is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EXAMPLE</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Hoa Dang">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/projects.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="EXAMPLE"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
        <style>
            @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
            </style>
    </head>

    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
            <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>

            <ul id="nav-ul">
                <li class="nav-li">
                    <a class="nav-link selected">HOME</a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-li">
                    <a class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-li">
                    <a class="nav-link">CV</a>
                </li>
 
                <li class="nav-li">
                   <a class="nav-link">PROJECTS</a>
                </li>

         
                <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </label>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div id="HOME">
            <div class="center">
                <h1 id="main-header">EXAMPLE</h1>
                <h3 id="sub-header">example.com <span class="green-detail">&</span> example.com</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="CV">
            <div class="center">
                <iframe src="example.com" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="PROJECTS" class="center">
            <div id="img-container"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="ABOUT">
            <div class="center">
                <h2 id="about-header">example.comE<span class="green-detail">:</span></h2>
                <p id="about-text">
                    <br> Text
                    <br> <br> 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <footer>
            <ul id="sm-ul">                
                <li class="sm-li">
                    <a class="sm-logo" href="example.com" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="sm-li">
                    <a class="sm-logo" href="example.com" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="sm-li">
                    <a class="sm-logo" href="example.com" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="sm-li">
                    <a class="sm-logo" href="example.com" target="_blank">
                        <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

:root {
    --base-color: #d2dae2;
    --secondary-color: #0be811;
}

body {
    background-color: #1e272e;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
    color: var(--base-color);
    overflow: scroll;
}

body::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url("example.com");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top-center;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: blur(7px);
}

nav, footer, #about-text, #contact-container {
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    margin-top: -30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 2;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5vh;
}


#about-text, #sub-header {
    font-size: 2.3vh;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight:400;
}

#main-header, #sub-header {
    text-align: center;
}

#main-header {
    font-size: 8.5vh;
}

#nav-ul {
    padding-right: 5vh;
}

#sm-ul, #nav-ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}


#about-header {
    font-size: 4vh;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.center, #contact-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 0;
}

.sm-logo {
    color: var(--base-color);
    font-size: 3vh;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

.sm-logo:hover, .nav-link:hover, .nav-link.selected, .green-detail {
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.sm-li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5vh;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.8vh;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav-li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5vh 5vh 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    nav, footer, #nav-top, #nav-ul, .nav-link {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #sm-ul, #nav-ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .sm-li {
        margin: 0 2vh 5vh 2vh;
    }

    .nav-li {
        margin: 5vh 2vh 0 2vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your website is not displaying as intended on your mobile is that you need more media queries to specify the layout and design according to the size. You have one media query. Change the size of your browser with the following media queries, and play around with the code so that it resembles your intended outcome:

```
/* Media Queries */

@media (min-width:320px)  { /* Vertical Screen Phones */ 
    
}

@media (min-width:480px)  { /* Horizontal/Landscape Screen Phones */ 
    
}

@media (min-width:600px)  { /* Tablets and Vertical iPads */
    
}

@media (min-width:801px)  { /* Tablet, Horizontal/Landscape iPads, low-resolution Laptops */
     
}

@media (min-width:1025px) { /* Big Tablets */
     
}

@media (min-width:1281px) { /* Laptops and Desktops */
    
}
```

Additionally, I'd recommend sticking to rem or em instead of vh. Its more widely used and more scalable.